# NSMutableArray denies to function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I'm planning to do editable array of strings. so first I created the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *history;
```

Then I made the lazy instatiation:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)history
{
    if (!_history) _history=[NSMutableArray array];
    return _history;
}
```

Now, when I just want to add an object to the array:

```
[self.history addObject:self.game.text]
```

(self.game.text is a NSString for that matter, but in Objective C I'm told it should receive any type of class)

and...even that simple method is not working. I'm not getting any error, it's just the simulator that stays on black screen, and the screen witch tells "Theard 1: signal SIGABRT"

No idea how to even start fixing it...
(When I remark the following line as a comment, the app works fine. That simple line seems to be creating the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory management, autoreleasing, weak-(property)-nesses and all this scary stuff that you haven't even heard about because you're living in the ARC dream.

To fix it:

```
if (!_history) self.history = [NSMutableArray array];
return _history;
```

Comment: @vikingosegundo I thank you for editing out the inappropriate "Xcode" tag.

Comment: I call it the Sisyphos tag

Comment: if _history is not null, set history to a new list, return history? How does this work?

Comment: This problem shouldn't happen with ARC. Instance variables are strong by default. The OP's problem is that he/she is *not* living the ARC dream.

Comment: @Chuck I would be extremely happy if that turned out to be right.

Comment: Can I have an explanation on this "ARC dream"? Both in xcode and in standford courses they do recommend using _history instead of self.history. How is it right to call self.history at the init stage?

Comment: @H2CO3 _history initializes to nil, so the logic would always return nil? Plus if you do self.history in the getter, does that not go back into the getter (and again...)?

Comment: @crashmstr 1. Of course, right, because I fail to type `!`. 2. No, think about it for a moment.

Comment: @H2CO3: From the ARC release notes: "With ARC, instance variables are strong references by default—assigning an object to an instance variable directly does extend the lifetime of the object." So if this ivar is defaulting to unsafe/unretained in ARC, that's a compiler bug. The more likely explanation IMO is that there's no ARC here.

Comment: is not self.history the same as [self history], which would use the getter?

Comment: @crashmstr: There is a huge difference between `self.history` and `self.history = x`. The former is `[self history]` and the latter is `[self setHistory:x]`.

Comment: After trying your fix (and also the one from the guy below) it's not working and still giving the same "error"...

Comment: @H2CO3 adding the ! just makes your code almost the same as the question.

Comment: @crashmstr Yap. The essence is in the details. If there really is no ARC, then my code works, OP's doesn't. And without the `!`, the logic is flawed.

Comment: Except the change of _history => self.history in the setter, I don't see any other difference...

Comment: @user2046387 Because there's no other difference.

Comment: but that difference is essential

Comment: @user2046387: Yes, that difference is extremely significant in non-ARC environments — one leads to the object being retained, the other doesn't. If you're still encountering trouble, it sounds like your problem is in most likely `self.game.text`. Because H2CO3's method here is fine (at least for single-threaded use).

Comment: After trying that difference, the end result showed no difference...same exact problem. Okay then, I will try right now to enter a simple general NSString just to check that's not the problem

Comment: @user2046387, did u overwrite the setter?

Comment: @user2046387, check with the debugger, that self.game and self.game.text really exist.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - the setter of history? nope. and about self.game.text, I've already used them successfully in different places at the same class...

Comment: now it gives me a new problem...the console opened and it loads it forever, the simulator again stuck at black screen

Comment: please update the code in your question with those you have now.

Comment: @user2046387: It doesn't matter if you've used them elsewhere. Something is clearly not working here, and given that H2CO3's method works, `self.game.text` is the only other possible culprit unless there's something you're not telling us about. Instead of adding `self.game.text`, try just adding `@"Test string"` to the array on that line. I bet that'll work.

Comment: it finished, it shows the green arrow stuck on the function history. and it wrote: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7fffdc)

Comment: it's right now with @"lalala". and this is the new function it has right now:

Comment: - (NSMutableArray *)history
{
    if (!self.history) self.history=[NSMutableArray array];
    return _history;
}

Comment: @user2046387: That should be `if (!_history)`. Calling `self.history` inside your `history` accessor is an infinite recursion.

Comment: Nobody here understands the difference between instance variables and properties? Getters and setters? Come on SO...

Comment: okay, the few ideas to fix confused me (the if() from below stayed and ruined my code), it finally works. gonna thank now H2C03

Comment: @user2046387 You're welcome. Now please 1. accept my answer, 2. head over to another tab in your web browser and search for Apple's advanced memory management guide.

Comment: the same goes for @crashmstr: I strongly recommend you to check apples docs about properties (again)